# use multiple files in category.tpl with smarty

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.6

`{$category->id|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}`
this smarty code is for get id number on category.tpl

we have lot of category id's `example 2,6,8,10` etc etc and in my folder lots of files names example `2minimum.txt, 6minimum.txt, 8minimum.txt, 10minimum.txt` etc etc

i want to use include file when current category id page with category id number txt file.

`{include file='folder/2minimum.txt'} <=-` this will work perfect when i put file name but i want to use like this

`{include file='folder/{$category->id|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}minimum.txt'}`

but it's give error

experts need you help to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `smarty cat` to concatenate variable to your file name. In your example it should look something like:

```
{include file='folder/'|cat:{$category->id|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}|cat:'minimum.txt'}
```

[Link to smarty documentation](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.cat.tpl)

Hope it helps, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
{include file='folder/'|cat:$category.id|cat:'minimum.txt'}
```

In smarty `{}` means `{this is smarty}`.

But you wrote `{this is smarty{what's this?}this is smarty}`.

It was a syntax error.

And I'm not sure, but I think `$category->id` is php code style. You could find `$category.id` is smarty code style in Prestashop template files.

And `$category.id` returns number. I don't think it needs `escape`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.